# add content through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a page where when you click on any of the three images. It inserts the content into the empty `div` above the image links.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click (function() { 
        $('.deal_content').append(<img src="deal_content.fw.png" width="587" height="299" alt="Your Deals!" />);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is the HTML it is to effect:

```
<div class="deal_content">

</div>
<div id="imagelink"> 
    <a href="#">
        <img src="for_men_btn.fw.png" width="200" height="87" alt="For Men" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="for_couples_btn.fw.png" width="200" height="87" alt="For Couples" />                     
    </a>    
    <a href="#">
        <img src="for_teens_btn.fw.png" width="200" height="87" alt="For Teens" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I wish the new image to be put in the `deal_content` class `div`.

Comment: y u use such old jQuery version? use `1.11.0` (latest)

Comment: Why are the images wrapped with `<a>` elements? it seems weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your append method, if you put double quotes around the HTML and replace the current quotes with single quotes, it should work. Append takes a string or a JQuery selector, not markup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the element a string in order to pass it through append

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('img').click (function() { 
   $('.deal_content').append('<img src="deal_content.fw.png" width="587" height="299" alt="Your Deals!" />'); 
   return false; 
 }); 
});
```

Comment: had to edit the psot so that the javascript showed as code isntead of text to see the img src. sorry

Comment: @user3461092 - Try wrapping the element in `''` in the argument.

Comment: thank you, now I just need to figure out how to make it its full size isntead of the width of the smaller images below it, doesn't seem to change when i change the width in the javascript argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imagelink').on('click', 'img', function(){ 
    $('.deal_content').append( this );
});
```

or if you want to duplicate the image:

```
$('#imagelink').on('click', 'img', function(){ 
    $('.deal_content').append( this.cloneNode() );
});
```

is that what you want? This way it will only move the images that are inside `imagelink` element

Answer (score 0):

Considerting this is what you want:

> I wish the new iamge to be put in the deal_content class div.

You are almost there:

In the Javascript that you have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        $('.deal_content').append();
        return false;
    });
});
```

you need a `html()` instead of `append()`. And insert a `img` tag, and grab the `src`from the image thatw as clicked on.

```
$('.deal_content').html("Image \"" + $(this).attr("src") +"\" here: <img src=" + $(this).attr("src") + "/>");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/PA63e/